# Замена (строка) в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

как заменить в тексте все части строки в скобках? например есть строка:

```
привет(какдела)чтоделаешь
```

как из строки убрать `(какдела)`?

Comment: Да регуляркой. Искать `\([^)]*\)`, менять на пустую строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью **регулярных выражений** в поиске.

В поле **поиск** пишите следующее:

```
\(([^\(]*)\)
```

Поле **Заменить на** оставляете пустым, и нажимаете **Заменить всё**. Таким образом у вас останутся только скобки, которые можно найти с помощью поиска, и удалить и их.

Comment: Какой смысл формировать группу, если она не будет использоваться?